# How to convert base 64 string to array of bytes without data loss?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, binaryfiles

I have a base 64 string. I want to write is at as bytes of array to  binary file(.dat)

I used the following code to do that. Please refer.

```
string s = "do+BmqbI81d3XT85OGtX965DkWqSg0Iqy47VSPNMrkH9TBR9XMg8jn4xI8VCZBxXrI6h17nWAdeRzZicQVHCibIFBiTPA7YM0pvYQwrk3npyxJ8GuFMYbFiIXlrvgg3S7LqCZ1Wy0LPmhc51qMQ2QZDwGDqTV/fdYFVuCoYj3Mw=";

            byte[] b = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);

            File.WriteAllBytes(@"D:\\newbin2.dat", b);
```

But i am not getting the result as expected. Binary file should not be human readable. I tried opening with notepad++ and i can able to see the same text eventhough i write it as bytes.

where am going wrong?

Comment: "human readable" is subjective; the binary is the binary. If it happens to contain things that look a lot like text, that isn't the fault of the binary. If you need *security*, you should *encrypt* it. In your UTF-8 example, the reason it is so **very** readable is that you have basically saved the base-64 as a string, rather than storing the underlying binary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are converting the string s to bytes using a wrong encoding. As you mentioned, it should be base64 encoded, not UTF8. Like this:

```
byte[] b = Convert.FromBase64String(s);
```

Comment: @ShafiqAbbas define "decoded" here... the code shown (very correctly, IMO) simply turns the base-64 back into the 128 bytes of actual data, and stores that.

Comment: Actually i should get 172 bytes from the string. but if i use, Convert.Frombase64string(), i am getting only 128 bytes.

Comment: @ShafiqAbbas no, you should get 128 bytes. You are mistaken. Base-64 takes **extra space** (thus appears longer) to store the same data, because it has to limit itself to only using 6 bits out of every character (which means 6 bits out of every byte, for downstream encodings like ASCII / UTF-8 / etc). 128 * 8 / 6 = 170.6 (so, 171 chars); plus padding (`=`) to get to a full block. Your 172 characters of base-64 only represents 128 bytes of actual data